# slow performance with exists case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Essentially I am trying to see if c_DSS_PG_Submission.PtNum is in the ED_MLP_ATTN temp table and if it is then assign 'MLP+ATTN'. The temp table alone takes about 2 minutes to generate and has ~1000 rows, the PG table has about ~300 rows so these are not big tables.  However the query below runs for 20+ minutes. Would you recommend anything different with the query? I've tried changing exists to IN but same slow performance.

```
WITH    ed_mlp_attn
          AS ( SELECT   smsdss.c_cfvhs_emstat_chart.visitno ,
                        CAST (smsdss.c_cfvhs_emstat_chart.dschdate AS DATE) AS dschdate
               FROM     smsdss.c_cfvhs_emstat_chart
                        INNER JOIN smsdss.c_cfvhs_emstat_oi_header ON smsdss.c_cfvhs_emstat_chart.chrtno = c_cfvhs_emstat_oi_header.chartno 
                             COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Pref_CP1_CI_AS
                        INNER JOIN smsdss.c_cfvhs_emstat_oi_detail ON c_cfvhs_emstat_oi_header.oi_header_id = smsdss.c_cfvhs_emstat_oi_detail.oi_header_id
                        INNER JOIN smsdss.c_cfvhs_emstat_physician ON smsdss.c_cfvhs_emstat_chart.erphys = smsdss.c_cfvhs_emstat_physician.physid
                              COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Pref_CP1_CI_AS
               WHERE    smsdss.c_cfvhs_emstat_chart.dschdate >= DATEADD(mm, -1,
                                                              GETDATE())
                        AND smsdss.c_cfvhs_emstat_chart.dispocd <> 'DXERR'
                        AND c_cfvhs_emstat_oi_detail.VALUE IN ( '21504',
                                                              '21505' )
                        AND smsdss.c_cfvhs_emstat_physician.code1 = 'RES'
             )
    SELECT  atndrname ,
            atndrno ,
            CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT   1
                               FROM     ed_mlp_attn
                               WHERE    visitno COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Pref_CP1_CI_AS = smsdss.c_dss_pg_submission.ptnum )
                 THEN 'MLP+ATTN'
                 ELSE 'NO'
            END AS ed_prov_type
    FROM    smsdss.c_dss_pg_submission
    WHERE   date_run = '2014-12-12'
            AND surveydesignator IN ( 'ER0101', 'PE0101' )
    ORDER BY surveydesignator ,
            ptnum
```

Comment: which rdbms you are dealing with? did you check indexes? any hint from the analysis tools of your rdbms?

Comment: Instead of using the correlated subquery, you could try to use an `outer join`.  As always though with performance, you'll need to test for yourself.  Make sure you have the appropriate indices as well.

Comment: MSSQl server 2008. My estimated execution plan has 68% cost for a clustered index scan of OI_HEADER. When i SELECT name AS Stats,
STATS_DATE(object_id, stats_id) AS LastStatsUpdate
FROM sys.stats says the table was updated 12/5/2014. Would this indicate that it was indexed as well? or should i reindex?

Comment: The query in the CTE will be executed for each row returned by outer query. It might help to put the results into a table variable and join that with c_dss_pg_submission. Without more information I can't be sure how much that will help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, a CTE is not the same as a temp table, note the information in [@JodyT's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27446903/slow-performance-with-exists-case-statement#comment43333719_27446903).

> The query in the CTE will be executed for each row returned by outer query.

This will slow down the query a great deal I'd expect. I would break down the current CTE in to an actual temp table as a starting point to improve performance.

**NOTE:** I've used aliases for table names to reduce the amount of SQL and make it a little easier to read.

```
SELECT  chart.visitno , CAST (chart.dschdate AS DATE) AS dschdate
INTO #TEMP
FROM    c_cfvhs_emstat_chart chart
        INNER JOIN c_cfvhs_emstat_oi_header header 
          ON chart.chrtno = header.chartno COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Pref_CP1_CI_AS
        INNER JOIN c_cfvhs_emstat_oi_detail detail 
          ON header.oi_header_id = detail.oi_header_id
        INNER JOIN c_cfvhs_emstat_physician physician 
          ON chart.erphys = physician.physid COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Pref_CP1_CI_AS
WHERE   chart.dschdate >= DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE())
        AND chart.dispocd <> 'DXERR'
        AND detail.VALUE IN ( '21504', '21505' )
        AND physician.code1 = 'RES'
```

Then query that:

```
SELECT  atndrname ,
        atndrno ,
        CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT   1
                           FROM     #TEMP
                           WHERE    visitno COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Pref_CP1_CI_AS = smsdss.c_dss_pg_submission.ptnum )
             THEN 'MLP+ATTN'
             ELSE 'NO'
        END AS ed_prov_type
FROM    smsdss.c_dss_pg_submission
WHERE   date_run = '2014-12-12'
        AND surveydesignator IN ( 'ER0101', 'PE0101' )
ORDER BY surveydesignator , ptnum
```

Breaking it down like this should improve performance by a degree, but without information on indexes and an execution plan, it's difficult to provide further advice.